# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, dynamic-linq

I am using *Dynamic LINQ* in an ASP.NET MVC project to create queries at runtime.

First I create a string from client's request like this:

```
string predicate = GetPredicateString(request);
```

The `predicate` would have a value like `"AvailableFrom = DateTime(2015, 10, 05)"`

Then in my code I call `ParseLambda` method of `DynamicLinq.DynamicExpression` class like below.

```
var lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(Product), typeof(bool), predicate)
```

Doing so I receive the following exception:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.**

```
Line 1958: int FindBestMethod(IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method){
Line 1959: MethodData[] applicable =
               methods
                   .Select(m => new MethodData
                   { 
                       MethodBase = m,
                       Parameters = m.GetParameters()
                           .Where(p => p.ParameterType != ((MethodInfo)m).ReturnType).ToArray()
                   })
                   .Where(m => IsApplicable(m,args)).ToArray();
```

this part of the above fragment must be throwing the exception:

```
(MethodInfo)m
```

I have tried to pass arguments matching other constructor overloads of `DateTime` structure, but it doesn't make any difference. So one can rule out passing invalid arguments being the cause.

I have to say that I am getting this exception only with `DateTime` and all other data types (`string`, `int` etc.) cause no problem.

I haven't found anything similar in the Internet, so I guess either I am doing something wrong or this is a very rare situation.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `ConstructorInfo` isn't a `MethodInfo`, so I'm not surprised that's failing. Why are you casting to `MethodInfo`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, this is the original code of Dynamic Linq library in `Dynamic.cs` file written by Microsoft not me!

Comment: Right, well basically it appears not to support constructors...

Comment: But it is meant to work with `DateTime` and understands `"DateTime"` in a string as a keyword.

Comment: Please copy and paste code, don't re-type it. You have introduced at least one syntax error that makes your question a lot harder to understand (missing `(`) by re-typing it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, a part of the "Dynamic Expressions and Quries in Link":

Types The expression language defines the following primitive types:
Object, Boolean, Char, String, SByte, Byte Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, Decimal, Single, Double, `DateTime`, TimeSpan, Guid

Comment: `(MethodInfo)m)` is that a typo?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh That's the one I was referring to. Looking up the actual source code online, yes, that is a typo, the actual source code has an extra `(`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, It is just a typo. The actual code is fine and builds without problem.

Comment: @hvd, I copied that from inside `where` method and that the cause of the missing `(`.

Comment: @Kamran It's wrong in your `Where`. What you put in the question is not the actual code. It can't be, because code with unbalanced parentheses won't compile.

Comment: wrong or not, he is casting when he doesn't need to. Just remove the `(MethodInfo)m` cast and  just use `m`.

Comment: Typo fixed. But @PhilippeParé this is the original code of the Dynamic Library. I did not write it.

Comment: @PhilippeParé That's what made it so confusing. It looked like it could just use `m` because of the missing `(`, but with the `(` added, it's clear why the cast is necessary: `MethodBase` doesn't have any `ReturnType` property.